# Run MySQL replication by schedule or on demand

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a master-slave replication currently configured. I know this setup runs real time. Is it possible to sync only the databases on schedule (daily or weekly) or by demand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-delayed.html
says

> MySQL 5.6 supports delayed replication such that a slave server
>   deliberately lags behind the master by at least a specified amount of
>   time. The default delay is 0 seconds. Use the MASTER_DELAY option for
>   CHANGE MASTER TO to set the delay to N seconds:
>
> `CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_DELAY = N;`
>
> An event received from the master is not executed until at least N
>   seconds later than its execution on the master. The exceptions are
>   that there is no delay for format description events or log file
>   rotation events, which affect only the internal state of the SQL
>   thread.

Comment: Thanks Rick! Is it possible to set this param in 24 hrs or days? And is it efficient?

Comment: As far as I know, any number of seconds will work.  So 86400 for 1 day.  It will need to queue up the replication queries, presumably on the Slave.  The queue already exists (the "relay log").  The size depends on how much is replicated -- maybe 1GB per day, maybe less, maybe more.

Answer (score 1):

On your Slave issue the `STOP SLAVE`, `START SLAVE` commands to stop / start replication on Demand. If you want to run it to a schedule write a batch file / cron to `STOP SLAVE` and `START SLAVE` at the required times. I'm assuming you have a good reason for doing this?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the reason is I don't want the records from master to be available immediately in the slave. The slave is exposed to the clients. There is a product table which has records that are subject for evaluation and review, however, due to the existing db design I cannot flag those records and the application is not capable in filtering those records.

Answer (score 0):

As for reference, in case somebody bumps here: I've used https://github.com/mrjgreen/db-sync to accomplish similar results.

Based on php, dbsync allows you to sync tables/records from host A to host B, including WHERE clauses (for when you need to pass records from one place to another). This directly thru' the command line.

I used it to make a gprs based database replication on a remote Rpi - without having to much time to make something dedicated or mess things up with database replication lol-.

Hope it helps.